# Replacing NaN in a column with median of a subset based on a different column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

First question here so please bear with me :)

My goal is to define a function that will replace the NaN values in the column 'total_income' with the median 'total_income' that I have calculated based on education level. The function should take the education level and then replace the NaN in total_income with the median based on the entries education level. The function outputs the correct numbers when I supply the education level directly to the function but  I am having trouble using .apply() to replace the total_income values in the dataframe.

I know that was long, any direction is greatly appreciated. Thank you!

```py
df_ed_med= df_drop.groupby('education')['total_income'].median()

def median_ed(education):
        if education == 'primary education':
            return df_ed_med['primary education']
        
        if education == 'secondary education':
            return df_ed_med['secondary education']
        
        if education == 'some college':
            return df_ed_med['some college']
        
        if education == "bachelor's degree":
            return df_ed_med["bachelor's degree"]
        
        if education == 'graduate degree':
            return df_ed_med['graduate degree']
```

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, you can try

```py
df['total_income'] = (df.groupby('education')['total_income']
                      .transform(lambda x: x.fillna(x.median())))
```

Comment: Thank you for your response! does this fill nan for 'total_income' with the median 'total income' for each education level?

Comment: @hannah_pella Yes, you can try it.

Comment: thank you so much. It worked perfectly, so much simpler than trying to write a whole function.